# use match statement when using neo4j driver, the returned result.record is nil

Tags: go, neo4j, cypher

match statement:

```
result, errRet = session.Run("MATCH (n) return n", nil)

log.Printf("hello here: %+v", result)
```

result:

```
&{err:<nil> iter:0xc00017c600 stream:0xc00072b020 cypher:MATCH (n) return n params:map[] allReceived:false unconsumed:{root:{next:<nil> prev:<nil> list:<nil> Value:<nil>} len:0} record:<nil> summary:<nil>}
```

actual data in db:

[image: actual data in db]

As i searched and couldn't find the answer. Plz show me which part i'm wrong, and very appreciated for it.

btw, create statement really works fine for me.

Comment: I'm not familiar with that driver but what's the nil for?

Comment: Thanks for ur comment, `nil` is the params map when invoke `run` func, maybe you are interested in [neo-go](https://github.com/neo4j/neo4j-go-driver).

Comment: I usually interact with my Neo4j instance either with the python driver or with neo4j-graphql-js. In either of those formats, you would only use the statement 
```
MATCH(n) return n. 
```
Maybe try it without the nil? It looks like in their documentation they include a map:
result, err := session.Run("CREATE (n:Item { id: $id, name: $name }) RETURN n.id, n.name", map[string]interface{}{
 "id":   1,
 "name": "Item 1",
})

Comment: Thanks for ur answer, nil is mandatory and and invoke func without the 2nd param. I 
 want to checkc whether there is an existing resource using result of `match (n) return (n)`, if yes then update, otherwise create. Finally i  found a way to work around it using `merge on create set` statement. Thanks again to u pal.

Answer (score 2):

Initially, the `result.record` field points to a position before the first record, so it is `nil`. You need to call `record.Next()` to move it to the first record. Usually it's done in a loop:

```golang
for result.Next() {
    log.Printf("The current record is: %+v", result.Record())
}
```

See [parsing result values](https://github.com/neo4j/neo4j-go-driver/tree/1.7/#parsing-result-values)